# C++14 supporting editor/IDE

Tags: ide, c++14

I'm looking for some powerful programming environment for C/C++. In fact the only think i need is powerful source navigating + creating tool. Doesn't matter if its free or commercial. I prefer some linux tool, but it doesn't have to be necessary linux app.

**What i need is some kind of editor with following capabilities:**

1. more open files + tabs/buffers switching
2. highlighting (+ bracket matching, folding, etc...)
3. save sessions
4. preview window(when the cursors stops on some symbol, i have also an preview window, that shows me the definition of that symbol)
5. searching for uses of the symbol through code
6. intelligent completion (must support c++ 14!)

**What would be nice:**

7. code beautifizier or something similar
8. utf-8 support
9. editor templates(for example automatic comment header for modules, functions...)
10. other editor scripting
11. a terminal/console accessible from program || compiling debugging capabilities(just for to be able to compile the whole project without switching extensively to command line)
12. program flow visualization

Please do anyone around the whole world knows anything, that knows all of that?

I've tried several editors/IDEs, but all of them misses something. I've decided to emphasise missing support for new c++14 - it's now probably the biggest problem:

- ### VIM

  - Amazing scripting capabilities
  - 4 and 6: i've tried to use vim+ctags+cscope and vim+gtags + omnicomplete. <s>But its not that usable. This doesn't work properly. Vim doesn't know c++ and it does not know the symbol context. Though i've been able to achieve basically the desired behaviour after hours of learning vim scripting, i'm not able to use it in even a little more complicated manner.(Lets say i have global variable and local variable with same names and different types - vim ofc does not recognize if im seeing now global or local only variable. And i'm not even talking about namespaces, etc....).</s> Actually VIM now support c++14 with the help of clang(libclang) and there is awesome plugin called YouCompleteMe, that can use libclang, and its auto-complete really workds with c++14 code! <s>**And it makes the vim the only editor supporting c++14.**</s>. This plugin is now more or less usable in more editors(vim, emacs, sublime). It adds autocomplete, jump to definition and error messages.
  - **c++14 supported**
- ### Source Insight

  - Amazing highlighting capabilities(different font for highlighting is amazing(especially for function names in function defintion header for example), also there is possibility to assign keyboard shortcut to cancel font differences, and leave only color highlighting(when you are bothered with different code alignment(due to different fonts)
  - Problems with 1) (though a hacked library for this called TabsSiPlus exists)
  - no terminal/console
  - Software is not maintained anymore, its not open source(and even not free) :(((
  - **c++14 support missing**
- ### SlickEdit

  - Amazing customizing possibilities, can emulate vim editing style(WOW!)
  - no terminal/console(actually there is one, but not that good, however it has builtin compiling capabilities
  - it has strange GUI - a lot of space is occupied by scrollbars, different window captions, etc..
  - its kinda expensive(comparing to others)
  - **c++14 support missing**
- ### Kdevelop4

  - Very pleasant GUI, nice console, very fast, can emulate vi editing style(not too well though)
  - miss force rescan/retag project (sometimes there are wrong symbol references, especially in bigger projects - this bugs me a lot)
  - its preview window doesn't show definition, only reference to definition, the definition then is showed in main editing window.. - cannot see actual code and the symbol definition at once :((
  - **c++14 support missing**
- ### Eclipse

  - nice environment with lots of functionality.
  - don't have ad4), however it has some sort of preview bubble. When you hover mouse cursor upon symbol, it will show a bubble with symbol definition. Its nice functionality, but unfortunately you need to use mouse, and its noway that user friendly as separate preview window.
  - also its a little slow, but i think its due to realtime syntax checking, and it probably will be disablable.
  - **c++14 support missing**
- ### Emacs

  - Support c++14 by similar plugins as vim(YouCompleteMe)(see in Vim section).
  - *Please can some proficient Emacs user fill in this section?*
  - **c++14 supported**
- ### Sublime Text 3

  - Not free
  - Support c++14 by similar plugins as vim(YouCompleteMe)(see in Vim section). Though i had some problems with it. Plugin was more unstable than in Vim for me.
  - Through different plugins it support more or less the same functionality(from user view) as vim.
  - **c++14 supported**

Do any of you use some different editor, that can do anything from the list above, or maybe some plugins/scripts that can achieve the demanded functionality?

Comment: I have used SlickEdit since 1998, over the years I used it on Windows, Linux, and now Mac, it has been worth it.  Yes the terminal is weak, but I guess I got used to not using it (only use  for compiling).  MacOS support is currently weak, but it seems to be on their radar.  For me - I would need to see all my favorite features elsewhere before I would consider switching.

Comment: Well, i have to agree, that this is the only piece of software that has all the features i need. I'll probably stick to it, though i dont like its gui. A lot space is occupied by scrollbars, window captions, etc... on the other hand, no other tool has near the same capabilities(except source insight, that would probably be better, if development hadnt stopped a years ago)

Comment: Check my question as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842650/c-c-source-code-browser-comparison-seeking-opinion

Answer (score 3):

Regarding VIm and your point 6, I have heard that [clang_complete](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3302), which is leveraging clang from LLVM compiler was quite accurate but I have not yet tested myself.

Comment: i'm trying to use it now. This clang compiler is somehow powerful and i feel a big potencial, but.. it needs a lot of work.

Comment: I use clang_complete. As autocompleters go it is extremely good. Only problem is that you have to configure it in your scripts :-(

Answer (score 0):

Try Eclipse, can handle almost everything (from Java to C with GNU Tools)

Comment: Im trying the eclipse out. So far i found out its kinda slow, but can do a lotlot.. but i havent found ad4) Do eclipse have some kind of preview window? I know, that i hover mouse cursor on symbol it shows me bubble with symbol definition, but is there possibility to have also window with the same info, that is autotamticallu updated, when cursor moves?

Comment: Try looking under the Views menu. If I recall correctly, at least for java and c++ dev, there was such a view (driven not by mouse but by the cursor). Try experimenting with "Perspectives" in order to get a grip of what Eclipse can do for you. Up to day, I still haven't found a better refactoring engine (visual studio 2010 it's a big epic fail regarding refactoring). For the slowness, try adding more memory to it's starting virtual machine (it's something about adding a -D<jvm-param> somewhere in a shell script). Regards.

Comment: Im probably blind or what, but i cannot find it. There is some super stuff like Type Hierarchy or Call hierarchy.. i like it already, but i cant find window, that shows me the same stuffs in separate window, as hovering mouse over symbol shows me in bubble. Wasnt there some plugins, that may do the stuff?

Comment: Window->Show View->Other->Java->Declaration guess for the C dev env there's something similar (there's also for JS). Don't worry about not seeing things, eclipse is just so huge, it's almost impossible remembering everything without having used it for at least some time. Have a nice evening.

Comment: So i've been looking for this, and unfortunatelly it works only in Java, not for c/c++ :(((

Comment: I bet there's an equivalent for C/C++. Try a research in eclips plugins

Comment: Havent found anything ..so i asked in the forums, but i doubt it... Anyway thank you for your patience and your help.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse supports c++14, all you need to do is to add -std=c++1y in your ***prefrences->C/C++->Build->Settings->Discovery*** 
for "*CDT Cross GCC Built-in Compiler Setting*" add "***-std=c++1y***"  at the end of compiler specs.

You also set the dialects in your project setting to support c++14,

Go to your project setting->C/C++ ***Build->Settings->GCC C++ Compiler->Dialect*** and select ***-std=c++1y***